# Two dimension array to single dimension and back again

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I was trying to find information about transforming an index that has been converted from a 2 dimensional index , to a single one. Then turn the single index back to a 2 dimensional one. I don't even know what this method is called.

formula to single index

```
  int index = x + y * width;
   MyArray[index] ;
```

So my question is how do I turn it back into two dimensions?

```
int x = index ??? width;
int y = index ??? width;
```

Can't wrap my head around it for some reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int x = index % width;
int y = index / width;
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir ,I suck when it comes to mod. Do you know the proper terminology for this multi to single indexing by any chance? So that I don't sound like a dummy next time :P

Comment: I'm not aware of any special terminology - maybe someone else can chip in ;-)

Comment: Single indexing is known (in Matlab) as linear indexing, the other you could call multi-dimensional indexing.

Comment: it assumes `0 <= x < width` and `0 <= y < height` and for index `0<= index < width*height`

Comment: I have never heard of negative indexes for matrices or arrays--do these exist in C#?

Comment: I'm basicly making a grid of 2d vectors , so their is negative positions involed sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

x = index % width; 
y = index / width;